# how to get a sub graph by using py2neo ogm

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I know hot to get the sub-graph by using Cypher query.
But since I use py2neo.ogm model. I just want to know how to get sub-graph by using ogm. for example:

```
class Company(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "firm_name"

    firm_name = Property()

    shareHolder = RelatedFrom("Company", "hold_by")
```

I already created the relationship between companies. I want to get the sub-graph of a company. I checked the document of py2neo, seems there is no example...
Anyone can help? 
    Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code (partly copied [py2neo v3 ogm doc](http://py2neo.org/v3/ogm.html)) produces the following movie titles list (not including the minus sign), when run with community edition of Neo4J with the movies sample (:play movies)

- Something's Gotta Give
- Johnny Mnemonic
- The Replacements
- The Matrix Reloaded
- The Matrix Revolutions
- The Matrix
- The Devil's Advocate
- A Few Good Men
- Apollo 13
- Frost/Nixon
- A Few Good Men
- Stand By Me
- A Few Good Men
- Top Gun
- Jerry Maguire

  ```
  import py2neo
  import py2neo.ogm

  from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
  from py2neo.ogm import GraphObject, Property, RelatedFrom, RelatedTo, RelatedObjects

  class Movie(GraphObject):
      __primarykey__ = "title"

      title = Property()
      tag_line = Property("tagline")
      released = Property()

      actors = RelatedFrom("Person", "ACTED_IN")
      directors = RelatedFrom("Person", "DIRECTED")
      producers = RelatedFrom("Person", "PRODUCED")


  class Person(GraphObject):
      __primarykey__ = "name"

      name = Property()
      born = Property()

      acted_in = RelatedTo(Movie)
      directed = RelatedTo(Movie)
      produced = RelatedTo(Movie)

  def authenticateAndConnect():
      # Authenticate the user using py2neo.authentication
      py2neo.authenticate('localhost:7474', '<username>', '<password>')

      # Connect to Graph and get the instance of graph
      return Graph('http://localhost:7474/default.graphdb/data/')     

  def foo():
      graph = authenticateAndConnect()
      for person in list(Person.select(graph).where("_.name =~ 'K.*'")):
          for movie in person.acted_in:
              print(movie.title)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      foo()
  ```

Comment: Hi Protable, thank you for your reply. But I found neo4jrestclient lib is much easier to use. I have give up py2neo...

Comment: by using neo4jrestclient. the thing is easy:

    from neo4jrestclient.client import Q
    import neo4jrestclient.client as client
    query_string = 'start a=node(%s) match (a)-[r:hold_by*]-(b) return a, r, b' % id
    results = gdb.query(query_string, returns=(client.Node, [client.Relationship], client.Node), data_contents=True)
    print results.graph

Comment: I believe it is as easy using py2neo. But you asked for an OGM example, which uses classes.

Comment: I found this answer useful. I hope that @Howardyan will accept this answer it answers the original question.